# dialogbox jquery without resizeable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i already used many dialogbox in my app.
but now, i dont want to use resizeable function anymore.

I know that "*resizable: false*" will turn off this function.
But, how to use it just once without put it one by one on every dialogbox constructor?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prototype the options for jQuery UI:

```
$.extend($.ui.dialog.prototype.options, {
    resizable: false,
});
```